# display icon based on file type

Tags: reactjs, axios, rendering

I want to display icons based on the file type. From the object that **I am fetching from strapi I can get the file extension**. But I want to render it dynamically on the table.

```
const TableData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getData = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:1337/document-uploads").then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      const myData = response.data;
      setData(myData);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => getData(), []);

  return (
    <div className="my-5">
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Icon</th>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Date created</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data &&
            data.map((file: File) => (
              <tr key={file.id}>
                <td>
                  {() => {
                    if (file.document.ext == ".pdf") {
                      return <img src={PDF} />;
                    } else if (file.document.ext == ".xml") {
                      return <XML />;
                    } else {
                      return <JPEG />;
                    }
                  }}
                </td>
                <td>{file.document.name}</td>
                <td>{file.description}</td>
                <td>{file.author}</td>
                <td>{file.created_at}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TableData;
```

I am getting the error: "Warning: Functions are **not valid as a React child**. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code without the anonymous function inside, just start from the if statement without everything wrapped inside a function.

```
                   {
                    if (file.document.ext == ".pdf") {
                      return <img src={PDF} />;
                    } else if (file.document.ext == ".xml") {
                      return <XML />;
                    } else {
                      return <JPEG />;
                    }
                  }
```

You can as well try different approaches with more modern javascript and ternary operators:

```
                   {
                    file.document.ext == ".pdf" ? <img src={PDF} /> : 
                    file.document.ext == ".xml" ? <XML /> : <JPEG />
                   }
```

Which is the same as the first code block.

Comment: Hi, thank for contributing, what you've written here is a good comment and, it might be correct. If this is as far as you want to go, then its should be a comment on the question and, not an answer. Otherwise, you should expand it with a code example of what you mean.